# Error 1004 when using =AND(ISERROR) formula in macro

Tags: vba, excel

I'm recording a macro to automate some Excel reports and have encountered the following bug whenever I try and run an iserror(search) formula:

> Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

I have two lists. The formula iterates through the first list and compares the values with those of the second list, hiding any matching values.

The formula in Excel is like this only with a wider criteria range:

```
=AND(ISERROR(SEARCH($B$3212,B2)),ISERROR(SEARCH($B$3213,B2)))
```

It works perfectly when I insert the formula directly into the spreadsheet cell however I get an error when I record and later run the macro using the same formula.

EDIT 2

I got the formula insertion to work through the macro but now I cannot filter the data as before, even when I do it manually without the macro.

Below is a link to a picture giving an example of the type of lookup I'm trying to achieve, previously it worked perfectly and removed all the rows which contained a string from the 'to remove list' now I cannot get it to filter at all. I've tried removing the macro after saving in notepad in case the file had become corrupted but it still does not filter as before. What could be causing this?

[This is how the lookup works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I85EU.png)

Cell [A13] would contain the aforementioned ISERROR formula in this example.

Comment: runtime error 1004 usually means you haven't defined an object correctly.  You'll need to post the code.

Comment: Runtime error 1004 is also generated when the formula you are trying to insert into a cell is not a valid Excel formula.  But, as @Dave says, you'll need to post the code if you want help.  (Or you can change your your `....Formula = "=....."` to `MsgBox "=....."` to see what formula you are trying to insert - you may be able to spot the problem yourself.)

Comment: As a rule of thumb it isn't a good idea to use worksheet solutions in VBA or v.v. Excel's ISERROR function demonstrates the point, as does your question. VBA offers better solutions, meaning clearer syntax which is easier to debug, so that you wouldn't even have this question had you used one of them instead of trying to force VBA into the ISERROR function. The same could be said for SEARCH. The fault is in the design. Your design is made for the worksheet. You shouldn't expect the macro recorder to be able to translate it correctly.

Comment: @Variatus - I'm not sure what you mean by "force VBA into the ISERROR function" (etc).  If the VBA code is just setting a cell's formula to be a string (which is what would have been recorded) then it won't matter what the contents of that string are, providing the string contains something that Excel (not VBA) can interpret.

Comment: @YowE3K - OP said that the formula is working on the worksheet but fails when recorded into VBA and run from the VB platform. Hence I understood that the problem results from VBA being asked to interpret an Excel function. Perhaps I got it wrong.

Comment: You can force VBA to use the ISERROR worksheet function by using `WorksheetFunction.IsError` but this isn't a good solution because then VBA throws an error and code execution stops if there actually is an error.  You could use On Error Resume Next but then the error gets suppressed and you will get the wrong answer in cases where an error did occur.  You could handle the error with a label but then you're getting into all kinds of machinations that make the code hard to read.

Comment: Until your code is included into the question, everyone is guessing at what your problem is caused by - please include it asap.

Answer (score 1):

This formula doesn't translate well to VBA in its current form.  You should use the VBA `Instr` function instead of the worksheet function Search.

```
Function FindSubstring() As Boolean

    Dim rngFindText As Range
    Dim rngWithinText As Range

    Set rngFindText = Sheet1.Range("B3212")
    Set rngWithinText = Sheet1.Range("B2")

    FindSubstring = InStr(rngWithinText, rngFindText)

End Function

Sub foobar()

    Debug.Print FindSubstring

End Sub
```

Comment: This solution demonstrates the difference between a solution based on worksheet functions and VBA and thereby shows the likely source of the error created in translation by the macro recorder. For both the ranges B3212 and B2 a worksheet must be specified. The worksheet function doesn't have that need, but in translation an error 1004 may occur if Excel can't identify the intended sheet. This likelihood is enhanced by the use of the SEARCH function of which only Excel knows how it identifies the location of the strings it works with, but unlikely in the same way as VBA does.

Comment: Can this solution be adapted to work across multiple ranges?

Comment: Yes, in that case you don't need the FindSubstring function at all, just pass the desired ranges to the Instr function.  If the substring is found then Instr will return the position of the first matching character within the string.  This will translate as TRUE if you want to use it as a boolean.  If the substring is not found within the string then Instr will return zero, which will translate as FALSE if you're looking to have a boolean returned.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking Excel a question to tell you to find the contents of $B$3212 in B2 and to find if again.

Usually the SEARCH is used to find the contents of one thing in another, by using it again the AND statement you are asking it again ... and for what?

Hence the question does not make sense.

What I think you might be asking if just once and if there is an error meaning it did not find it there in this instance for it to return 0.
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH($B$3212,B2)),0,SEARCH($B$3212,B2))

Comment: OP has stated that the formula is working when entered directly, but not when entered automatically by `vba` - the answer you have given does not address the question asked.

Comment: Re "and to find if again" - the original formula was `=AND(ISERROR(SEARCH($B$3212,B2)),ISERROR(SEARCH($B$3213,B2)))` which is using `$B$3212` and `$B$3213`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this one out, the original 1004 error was caused by vba only partially recording the formula, the solution involved simply going into the debugger to find which line hadn't been translated correctly and editing that line. I then had to edit the formula so as to be able to filter out values acording to my criteria and ended up with a formula closer to this:

```
       =AND(ISERROR(SEARCH("Value1",B2)), ISERROR(SEARCH("Value2",B2)))
```